# Hibernate:Could not read entity state from ResultSet and IllegalArgumentException:GregorianCalendar.computeTime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I'm beginner in JPA and hibernate and I'm just trying to fetch some data from my DB via hibernate but I failed and I got this error :

```
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:28 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing qPersistenceUnitInfo [name: NewPersistenceUnit]
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:29 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.2.Final}
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:29 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:30 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:30 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopping]
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:30 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:30 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:30 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:32 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:33 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@35e478f] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: 
    select
        itemclass0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        itemclass0_.author as author2_0_0_,
        itemclass0_.available_amount as availabl3_0_0_,
        itemclass0_.bought as bought4_0_0_,
        itemclass0_.imageURL as imageURL5_0_0_,
        itemclass0_.name as name6_0_0_,
        itemclass0_.price as price7_0_0_,
        itemclass0_.publish_time as publish_8_0_0_ 
    from
        item itemclass0_ 
    where
        itemclass0_.id=?
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: MONTH
Apr 29, 2019 5:14:33 AM org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener doOnLoad
INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[entities.ItemClass#58]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[entities.ItemClass#58]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3519)
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[entities.ItemClass#58]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4279)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1287)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2930)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2911)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2867)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2911)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3552)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: MONTH
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:847)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DateTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DateTypeDescriptor.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3014)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:305)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: MONTH
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.createFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:80)
    at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.createFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:46)
    at com.mysql.cj.result.BaseDecoratingValueFactory.createFromDate(BaseDecoratingValueFactory.java:53)
    at com.mysql.cj.result.BaseDecoratingValueFactory.createFromDate(BaseDecoratingValueFactory.java:53)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:72)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:90)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:250)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNonStringValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:656)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDateOrTimestampValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:679)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2648)
    at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
    at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
    at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.createFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:77)
    ... 42 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and Also type of publish_time column is date.

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>entities.ItemClass</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopping"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="****"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**This is my Entity Class**

**ItemClass.java**

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item", schema = "shopping", catalog = "")
public class ItemClass {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Integer price;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Integer availableAmount;
    private Integer bought;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date publishTime;

    private String author;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = true)
    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "imageURL", nullable = true, length = 45)
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "available_amount", nullable = true)
    public Integer getAvailableAmount() {
        return availableAmount;
    }

    public void setAvailableAmount(Integer availableAmount) {
        this.availableAmount = availableAmount;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "bought", nullable = true)
    public Integer getBought() {
        return bought;
    }

    public void setBought(Integer bought) {
        this.bought = bought;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "publish_time", nullable = true)
    public Date getPublishTime() {
        return publishTime;
    }

    public void setPublishTime(Date publishTime) {
        this.publishTime = publishTime;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "author", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ItemClass itemClass = (ItemClass) o;
        return id == itemClass.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, itemClass.name) &&
                Objects.equals(price, itemClass.price) &&
                Objects.equals(imageUrl, itemClass.imageUrl) &&
                Objects.equals(availableAmount, itemClass.availableAmount) &&
                Objects.equals(bought, itemClass.bought) &&
                Objects.equals(publishTime, itemClass.publishTime) &&
                Objects.equals(author, itemClass.author);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, price, imageUrl, availableAmount, bought, publishTime, author);
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import entities.ItemClass;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        ItemClass item = entityManager.find(ItemClass.class,58);

        System.out.println(item.getAuthor());


    }

}
```

I reviewed another questions that were similar to my title but It doesn't help.
can anyone plz help me to solve this issue ?

---

**UPDATE**

These are my rows with publish_time columns:

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLhiW.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is likely a data issue (in the database table).

A mysql table could contain datetime / timestamp entries like `2019-00-00`.  While such dates are valid in mysql (depending on the server version and mode), they will cause an exception when the mysql driver tries to parse them into Java dates.

Double check that the rows you are trying to retrieve have valid dates in the `publish_time` column.

ps. if you have all zero dates (`0000-00-00 00:00:00`) then you can use the `zeroDateTimeBehavior` property in the connection string to handle them more gracefully without changing the database values.

Comment: I updated my question and added picture of my table. it seems that all of the rows have valid date in the publish_time column.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on.  The other "weird" thing I see is in ItemClass.java -- it looks like your publishTime is java.sql.Date.  However, the @Temporal tag is actually not compatible with java.sql.Date (must use java.util.Date instead) so I'm wondering how that's working at all.   What happens if you update id #58's publishDate to some other date? (like today's date?) .  Also what's the timezone setting?  If you want to put a minimal version of the code & db tables somewhere (like on GitHub) we can examine it more closely.